# Splitting a debug msg to extract a certain part of the msg in ansible

Tags: ansible

So I need to take a particular part of my debug msg that I have in my playbook that goes like

```
---
  - name: extract  
    shell: grep "ScriptAlias /.*/" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    register: st

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ st.stdout_lines | map('trim') | list }}"
```

and that playbook prints out when ran

```
ok: [52.61.71.178] => {
    "msg": [
        "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ \"/var/www/cgi-bin/\""
    ]
}
```

So what I need to do is put that msg `"ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ \"/var/www/cgi-bin/\""`in an array and extract the last element in that which is the `"/var/www/cgi-bin/"`

What is the best approach in extracting the last element in my msg to where it can get only the `"/var/www/cgi-bin/"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below. Only added regex_replace (Answer From Valdimir) to get exactly what you want.

```
     - hosts: localhost
       vars:
         lines:
           - "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ \"/var/www/cgi-bin/\""
       tasks:
        - debug:
           msg: "{{ item.split(' ')[2] | regex_replace('\"', '') }}"
          loop: "{{ lines }}"
```

Output should be exactly as ::
       `"msg": "/var/www/cgi-bin/"`

Answer (score 0):

The split method works fine. Output is abridged.

```
> ansible-playbook split_test.yml
    "msg": "\"/var/www/cgi-bin/\""
```

**split_test.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost                                                                           
  vars:                                                                                      
    lines:                                                                                   
      - "ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ \"/var/www/cgi-bin/\""                                        
  tasks:                                                                                     
    - debug:                                                                                 
        msg: "{{ item.split(' ')[2] }}"                                                      
      loop: "{{ lines }}"
```